# Mac OS X Terminal - "cd.." does not work in terminal

Tags: linux, macos, bash

Currently, the "cd.." command no longer seems to be operating on my Mac.

See error below:

`ShanMacBook-Pro:Documents ShanMacbookPro$ cd..
-bash: cd..: command not found`

Not sure if it is a path issue:

`Shan-MacBook-Pro:Documents ShanMacbookPro$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

My machine:

- Macbook Pro Late 2014
- Yosemite 10.10.4
- NodeJS installed
- MeteorJS installed
- Git installed

Comment: As Evan said, space between "cd" and ".." .

Comment: Some Linux distros alias 'cd..' to 'cd ..', hence the confusion.

Answer (score 13):

Use `cd ..`

You need a space between the cd and the ..

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you.  Wow, I am an idiot .

Comment: No as much as you think.  When I started studying computer sciences in the 90s, a joker put a command called `cd..` into the directory `/home/pub/bin/` which many careless users had in their path.  The program simulated a DOS reboot (on a SunOS machine!) and then returned to the situation before that.  It really happened more than once that someone typed `cd..` and experienced a steep learning curve in the next minute.